# Problem with my ssh in ubuntu 14?

Tags: 14.04, ssh, debian

When I tried to connect from my Debian to my Ubuntu 14 appear this message below

[image: here]

What is necessary to do for fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has the target system been reinstalled recently? This happens because your system recorded the host key of the old target system, but now the host key has changed, probably due to a reinstallation of the system. To make your system forget the old key of the target system, do `ssh-keygen -R 192.2.1.151`.

Comment: Probably also have to remove the entry for the machine with the new key from the known_hosts file as well to stop ssh complaining about that entry also being bad.